# Ember JS index route with modal outlet

Tags: ember.js

I try to make a menu with

- a list view (**posts**)
- each item of the list should have its subroute, an independent view, without the list (**posts/post/1**)
- menu should always have its `active` class
- a `new` route under the list view. (In my application it is actually a modal over the list)

I have managed to solve this, except for the last one:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/marafumove/1/edit?html,js,output

**posts/new** should render under the posts list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to the new route rendered under the posts. So instead of rendering the list in the `post/index` route, use just the `post` route.

Use

```
script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts"
```

instead of

```
script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts/index"
```

And use

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
```

instead of

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
```

To render an individual post without the list, render it into the application template by overriding the `renderTemplate` method.

```
App.PostsPostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(post) {
    return post;
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ into: 'application' });
  }
});
```

[**Here is the updated demo.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qezowo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: thanks, but as I wrote: "each item of the list should have its subroute, an independent view, without the list (posts/post/1)". Now if I go to eg Post1's route, I can still see the list with all posts.

Comment: @blessdenm excellent! pls update your answer so I can accept. In the meanwhile I solved it too. I used the index approach: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/dabogutuli/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Updated the answer. Good that you found an alternative solution.